# Building out multiple src and href from the text of an element on the page (best method)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href, src

I've just finished a function that works, but I'm wondering if it's the best way.

My goal is to have the text in an h2.product-title add into both src paths of images and the href of a button to build out the complete path that matches what's on disk already—saving me time from manually linking assets. So when I duplicate a page and change out the text of the h2, the assets point to the right place.

**Here is the html from the page:**

```
<h2 class="product-title">Darth Vader</h2>

<img class="product-image" src="images/placeholder/preview-01.jpg">
<img class="product-image" src="images/placeholder/preview-02.jpg">
<img class="product-image" src="images/placeholder/preview-03.jpg">
<img class="product-image" src="images/placeholder/preview-04.jpg">

<p><a class="product-download" href="#">Download</a>
```

Inside "images", I have a "placeholder" folder and also a "products" folder. I have each product name in its own folder inside products. The placeholder folder is just for me to see temp images while building.

**The folder structure is like this:**

images/products/darth-vader/preview-01.jpg, ...

images/products/bespin-luke-skywalker/preview-01.jpg, ...

images/products/jabba-tha-hutt/preview-01.jpg, ...

**And my javascript:**

```
$(document).foundation();

$(function() {

  var str = $(".product-title").text();
  str = str.replace(/\s+/g, "-").toLowerCase();

  $(".product-image").attr("src",function(index,attr){
      return attr.replace("images/placeholder", "images/products/" + str );
});

  $(".product-download").attr("href", "images/products/" + str + "/download.zip");
});
```

Is this the right way to go about this? The downside to this is that I briefly see the placeholder image load before the actual image changed via js.

PS: I'm using a system that doesn't allow server-side scripting, so Javascript is the only thing I can do to modify the DOM.

Comment: my two cents - Don't do this on client browser, this logic belongs on the server.

Comment: I'm using a blogging platform that doesn't allow for server-side scripting... I should have mentioned that above.

Comment: Try wrapping your function in a DOMContentLoaded event listener:

`<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    //your function here
  });
</script>`

This will fire when the DOM is parsed, but before resources (like images) are loaded.

Comment: Thanks, Joel! I have this snippet currently at the bottom of my page. Would I need to add it in the head to get it to work?